# how to read data from junction table code first approach

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

how can I retrieve data from junction table in Code first approach.i know i can add data like this.

```
 Movie.Tag.Add(item)
```

but want to know how to get back those data in the junction table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you all rows in the junction table - each row is represented as an anonymous object with the two Ids of the row as properties:

```
var junctionTableDataList = (from m in context.Movies
                             from t in m.Tags
                             select new
                             {
                                 MovieId = m.MovieId,
                                 TagId = t.TagId
                             }).ToList();
```

You can add a `where` clause before the `select` if you want to limit the result to a specific or a few movies.

**Edit**

The same with extension methods and lambda expressions would look like this:

```
var junctionTableDataList = context.Movies
    .SelectMany(m => m.Tags.Select(t => new
    {
        MovieId = m.MovieId,
        TagId = t.TagId
    }))
    .ToList();
```

**Edit 2**

If you want return the data from a method you can create a litte helper type and return a list of those "named" objects instead of anonymous objects:

```
public class JunctionData
{
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }
}

List<JunctionData> junctionTableDataList
    = (from m in context.Movies
       from t in m.Tags
       select new JunctionData
       {
           MovieId = m.MovieId,
           TagId = t.TagId
       }).ToList();
```

Or `...Select(t => new JunctionData...` for the extension method syntax.

Comment: What of if i want do this in lambda expression

Comment: thank for your answer once again.i want to be able to return the junctionTableDataList so that i can have access to my MovieId in the junction table.but is an anonymous type. how do i go about this. thanks

Comment: your answer has been very helpful. My problem now is that i want to select all movies that has specific Tag ID. for example, i want to select all movies that has tag id =2. thanks

Comment: @JED: Please create a new question for this. It doesn't fit anymore to your initial question. You can also click on the white check mark on the left side of the answer to indicate that it solved the problem described in your question. (It's good practice here on Stackoverflow to "accept" answers this way, if they solved your problem.)